# Uncaught typeerror: object#<object> has no method addMsg

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Guys i am building a chatroom similar to yahoo chat. Have got an error while implementing one to one chat. The thing is that I am using a jQuery plug in to add and manage chat boxes.
the plugin is 
you will find the code for chatbox plugin in the below link

http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/chatbox.html

the problem is that i am getting an error in my console that addMsg is not found. I tried to research about it(to check if the headers are repeated) but I am not able to find a solution.
my chatroom code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML >
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>chat room</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/css/jquery.ui.chatbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/js/jquery.ui.chatbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/js/chatboxManager.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body style="background-image:url(http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/341/2/0/extremely_simple_youtube_background_by_rainmeterarts-d4ignxm.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: 310px 0px;">

     <fieldset id="field1" style=" margin:180px;
 margin-left:570px;
 font-family:verdana;
 width:278px;
 border-style:groove;
 border-color:#8AB8E6;
 border-width: 1em;">
 <h2 style="font-family:verdana;color:#336680;">chat box</h2>


 <div id="div1">
<textarea  id="display" class="textarea1" rows="20" cols="35" disabled style="font-family:verdana;font-size:1em; border-style:solid;background:transparent;"></textarea>
</br>
</div>


<div id="div2">
<form name="form" action="/Say"   method="GET" id="form"  enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" id="textbox1" style=" height:40px; width:215px;border-style:groove;">
<input type="button" value="send" class="submit" id="login" onclick="say();" style=" height:40px;width:80px;">
</form>
</div>

</fieldset >

<div id="friendsListPage">
        </div>



<form name="input" action="/chatroom"  method="GET" id="form1"  enctype="text/plain">
<fieldset id="field2" 
style="margin:290px;
margin-left:550px;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:1em;
width:348px;
border-style:groove;
border-color:#8AB8E6;
border-width: 1em;">

<h2 style="font-family:verdana;color:#336680;">LOG IN TO CHAT</h2>

USER_ID: <input type="text" id="textbox2" name="clientid" style=" height:40px;width:165px;border-style:groove;">

<input type="button" value="login" class="button" id="login" style="font-size:1em;font-family:verdana; height:40px; width:80px">

</fieldset>

     <div id="chat_div">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="log">
    </div>
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

var clientid;
var flag=0;
var counter = 0;
var idList = new Array();

 $(document).ready(function(){


$("#field1").hide();

     $(".button").click(function(){
          clientid = $("#textbox2").val();

    $("#field2").hide();
    $("#field1").fadeIn(2500);



            var form=$('#form1');

    $.get(form.attr('action'),$(form1).serialize(),function(data,status){

        $('#display').val(" Welcome to our chatroom "+clientid);




        channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(data.token);

        socket = channel.open();

        socket.onopen = onOpened;

        socket.onmessage = onMessage;

        socket.onerror = onError;

        socket.onclose = onClose;




                                                                        }
                                )
                                    });

                                });

 function onOpened() {
     // event handler from when Connection has established.

                    }

 function say() {



     // send message to server, to be distributed to all
     $.ajax({ 
        url:"/Say", 

        type: "GET",
        data:"message="+$("#textbox1").val()+"&clientid="+clientid, 
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
         {


         }

     });

     $('#textbox1').val('').focus();
     return false;
 }

 function onMessage(msg) 
 {
     var x=1;

     var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);


     if(obj.msgtype=="cidlist")
         {

         if(flag==0){

             flag=1;

            var friendslist= new Array();
                for ( x in obj.clientidlist)  {

                     if(obj.clientidlist[x]===clientid)
                        {

                        return;
                        }
                     else
                        {

                        friendslist.push(obj.clientidlist[x]);
                        var a = "<a id='"+friendslist[x]+"' >"+friendslist[x]+"</a>";
                        var txt = document.createElement("div");
                        txt.innerHTML = a;
                        txt.style.cursor="pointer";
                        txt.setAttribute("onclick","openchat(\""+friendslist[x]+"\");");
                        document.getElementById("friendsListPage").appendChild(txt);


                        }   

                                            }


                      } 

          }

     else if(obj.msgtype=="joinedchatroom")
         {
         $('#display').val($('#display').val()+msg.data+"                                                                                             ");
         var a = "<a id='"+obj.clientid+"' >"+obj.clientid+"</a>";
            var txt = document.createElement("div");
            txt.innerHTML = a;
            txt.style.cursor="pointer";
            txt.setAttribute("onclick","openchat(\""+obj.clientid+"\");");
            document.getElementById("friendsListPage").appendChild(txt);



         }
     else if(obj.msgtype=="private")
         {
         var x=0;
         var e=0;
        alert("new msg from "+obj.sender +" msg is "+ obj.message);
         for(var i=0;i<idList.length;i++)
             {
              if(obj.sender==idList[i])
                  {
                  alert("inside if");
                  $("#" + idList[i]).chatbox("option", "boxManager").addMsg(obj.sender, obj.message);  //getting an error on this line

                  e++;
                  }
             }
         if(e==0)
             {
         openchat(obj.sender,obj.message);
             }

         }




 }


 function openchat(reciever,msg) {

      chatboxManager.init({messageSent : function(reciever,msg)
           {
          alert("reciever is"+reciever);
          $("#" + reciever ).chatbox("option", "boxManager").addMsg(clientid, msg); //error on this line
           $.ajax({ 
                url:"/Privatemessage", 
                type: "GET",
                data:"message="+msg+"&reciever="+reciever+"&sender="+clientid, 
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                 {


                 }

                 });

            }

                         });



   var id = reciever;
   idList.push(reciever);

   chatboxManager.addBox(id, 
                           {dest:"dest" + counter, // not used in demo
                            title:"box" + counter,
                            first_name: id,
                            last_name: "sender "+clientid

                           });

   alert("end");
   event.preventDefault();


}


 </script>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The message is pretty explanatory, there is no `addMsg` method of whatever value is returned by `chatbox("option", "boxManager");`. Without seeing the code of `chatbox` we can't help. Also, please format your code correctly. It's almost unreadable at the moment.

Comment: why are you using two versions of jquery?

Comment: Sorry guys was in a hurry as I should submit it by today....lots left to do...give me some time ll format it....